# $W=\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2=0, \ \ \mbox{where} \ \ x,y \in \mathbb{R} \}$. Is $W \subset \mathbb R^2$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> $W=\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2=0, \ \ \mbox{where} \ \ x,y \in \mathbb{R} \}$. Is $W \subset \mathbb R^2$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

I think it is  subspace because there is only one vector that belongs to $W$, i.e., $(0,0)$. When we go with vector addition and scalar multiplication we get a vector that belongs to $W$. So, it is subspace.

Comment: $W=\{(0,0)\}$. Can you finish?

Comment: $W = { (0, 0) }$. You can easily verify that the subspace properties hold for $W$.